# youtube video download android

Tags: android, video, youtube, download

Can someone please tell me how to encode/decode (in android) the youtube URL which is indirect to a direct URL so as to download the video from Youtube ?? I tried the possible ways to convert the actual indirect URL and encode them to provide another URL which consists of hexadecimal values in it. But this method is not working as I'm not able to parse the URL to download the video using my download manager class. Thanks to all those developing genius out here in this forum to help beginners like me. Thanks in advance for those who give me a solution.

PS: This is done just for the personal use and not for commercial use. Also, I am doing this just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps:

Step 1: Check the sorce code (HTML) of YouTube, you'll get the link like this (http%253A%252F%252Fo-o.preferred.telemar-cnf1.v18.lscache6.c.youtube.com%252Fvideoplayback ...);

Step 2: Decode the url (remove the codes %2B,%25 etc), create a decoder with the codes: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp and use the function Uri.decode(url) to replace invalid escaped octets;

Step 3: Use the code to download stream:

```
URL u = null;
InputStream is = null;  

     try {
              u = new URL(url);
              is = u.openStream(); 
              HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();//to know the size of video
              int size = huc.getContentLength();                 

          if(huc != null){
              String fileName = "FILE.mp4";
              String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
              File f = new File(storagePath,fileName);

              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int len1 = 0;
              if(is != null){
                 while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                       fos.write(buffer,0, len1);   
                 }
              }
              if(fos != null){
                 fos.close();
              }
          }                     
     }catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
               try {                
                 if(is != null){
                   is.close();
                 }
               }catch (IOException ioe) {
                     // just going to ignore this one
               }
    }
```

Comment: Bro I am totally confused by this method.. Already looked into this. The actual url of the video would be like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQBTd4xF6tU
If you encode it , then you find something like this : 
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPQBTd4xF6tU
After this is where I have my doubt.. What should I do with this encoded URL ?

Comment: Decoding this link (https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPQBTd4xF6tU) will again get me back to the normal indirect youtube link. So am totally confused with this..

Comment: please give me your gmail id

Comment: k.krishnan.90@gmail.com.. So you giving me a proper explanation on how to go about with this ?

Comment: Please send me the tutorial through mail and leave your comment .. The moment its there in my inbox , I will go through it and let you know if its working or not.

Comment: Dude... Please I would request someone to help me on this. I just want to build my knowledge on how to do things .. If there's any of my friends who are interested in buying your application.. I will share the demo one you had sent me. Then I will contact you..

Comment: But for now.. If you can help me on how to go about the process which you explained in your answer above , I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: i sent you mail please go through it and revert me on my mail